# Why message "All your photo sources are hidden. To show some, change your settings" appears whenever I try to display a photo on windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I cannot display the screen. Maybe because every time I try to open a picture, I get the above message.

I saw a "solution" on  youtube, but going to settings does not give me and "options" option.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ucQyJyXOPdY

Answer (score 0):

It must have the settings option. Press the Win + C Key to open the charms bar and see it's there. Update to the newest version of the photos app from the App store and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the photo screen displayed where the message is displayed, THEN press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> key. This will give you the Options menu.

If you come back to the desktop & press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> key, the "Option" is not displayed.